# MongoDB - arrayFilters and updateMany from same document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-update

I have the following sample of data:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  seniorityDate: '2001-01-01T00:00:00Z',
  assigned: [
    {
      groupId: 11,
      system: 'Dep',
      effectiveDate: null
    },
    {
      groupId: 12,
      system: 'Team',
      effectiveDate: null
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

and I would like to update the object `effectiveDate` based on `seniorityDate` in the array of `assigned` where `system:'Team'` only:

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, 
[{
    $set: {
        'assigned.$[elem].effectiveDate': '$seniorityDate'
    }
}], {
    arrayFilters: [{
        "elem.system": "Team"
    }]
})
```

but I got the following error:

> arrayFilters may not be specified for pipeline-syle updates

---

The expected result will be:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  seniorityDate: '2001-01-01T00:00:00Z',
  assigned: [
    {
      groupId: 11,
      system: 'Dep',
      effectiveDate: null
    },
    {
      groupId: 12,
      system: 'Team',
      effectiveDate: '2001-01-01T00:00:00Z'
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `arrayFilters` with the aggregation pipeline at the same time. While you are updating the value from another field, hence you can only achieve with aggregation pipeline.

1. `$set` - Set `assigned` field.

   1.1. `$map` - Iterate element in `assigned` array and return new array.

   1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge current iterated document with the document from *1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1. Document with `effectiveDate` field. With the `$cond` operator, if matches the condition, use the `seniorityDate` value, else remain the existing value.

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "assigned": {
        $map: {
          input: "$assigned",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                effectiveDate: {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this.system",
                        "Team"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: "$seniorityDate",
                    else: "$$this.effectiveDate"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Thanks to @rickhg12hs' suggestion, always limit the document for better performance, as you know which document/field should be updated by condition.

Hence your update query with query condition will be as below:

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  "assigned.system": "Team"
},
[
  ...
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a6Lp-7Ejnxd)

Comment: Since only documents with `"assigned.system": "Team"` should be updated, you could add that as a filter to `updateMany`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, limit the documents for better query performance. Thanks for the suggestion. =)

Comment: Thanks, @rickhg12hs for your valid suggestion.